# How to create a mock test for OSB proxy service

Tags: oracle, osb

I have created a proxy service based on wsdl, which is not exposed, so can we create a simulator to test the proxy service.

Please help me the steps to create simulator using SBConsole, and i have developed the OSB service in 11gR1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand the question a little, what do you mean by create simulator?

I can suppose that you want:

1. Send request to your created proxy? You can use for example SoapUI to achieve it. Import your soap project and then call request. [Here](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/your-first-soapui-project.html#wsdl)  you got sample.
2. Send request to created proxy, and then send it from osb to mock (your external service simulator)? To that purpose you also can generate mock from SoapUI. Sample to create mock is available [here](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/service-mocking-overview.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

The point no.2 will solve my problem,

And my question is, how to test a OSB service when we dont have source/target services available.

Comment: The easiest way is use your generated mock, and implement/test using it. So you don't need exeternal service available. When you finish your implementation/tests, you just need change your source endpoint. if nothing has been changed in external services, everything should work correctly

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and it worked well and made easy to complete my task.